# Get ROWCOUNT from INSTEAD OF TRIGGER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

A legacy app does an INSERT on a table with an instead of trigger and subsequently uses the rowcount for further processing.

We now need to opt out of certain INSERTs with the use of an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger.

The problem is that @@ROWCOUNT still returns the number of **attempted** inserts.

For example, a fictitious trigger that will never complete an insert might be

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_ACCOUNT_CREDITS_RunningTotalINSERT]
   ON  [dbo].[ACCOUNT_CREDITS] 
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
 --tried with NOCOUNT ON and OFF
 SET NOCOUNT OFF;

 --This is an example of the branching logic that might determine 
 --whether or not to do the INSERT
IF 1=2 --no insert will ever occur (example only)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.ACCOUNT_CREDITS (COL1, COL2)
    SELECT COL1, COL2 from INSERTED
END
END
```

and some INSERT statements might be

```
--No rows will be inserted because value of COL1 < 5
INSERT INTO dbo.ACCOUNT_CREDITS (COL1, COL2) VALUES ( 3, 3)

--We would assume row count to be 0, but returns 1
select @@ROWCOUNT

--No rows will be inserted because value of COL1 < 5       
INSERT INTO dbo.ACCOUNT_CREDITS (COL1, COL2) 
SELECT 1, 1
union all
SELECT 2, 2

--We would assume row count to be 0, but returns 2
select @@ROWCOUNT
```

I can work around the issue, but it bothers me that I can't trust @@ROWCOUNT.  I can find no reference to this issue on SO or those *other* knowledge banks.  Is this simply a case of *TRIGGERS ARE EVIL?*

Can I affect @@ROWCOUNT?

Comment: I mean decide whether or not to actually conduct the INSERT.  Depending on the values of the INSERTED TABLE, no INSERT might occur.  I'll update my question so its clearer.

Comment: When you've got one INSTEAD OF trigger whose action you're trying to override by using another INSTEAD OF trigger my gut reaction is you've got too much logic in triggers, and you may have been drawn in by the Dark Side of the Database.  That way lies madness.  Turn back, turn back, before it's too late!  Aiiieeee!  Cthulhu fthagn!!!  (Don't ask me how I know...)

Comment: @Bob.  I love the "abandon all hope" sentiment and hear you loud and clear.  What I'm looking at in this case is a single trigger that may or may not do the insert depending on "stuff".  Nefarious still, but why can't I get an accurate row count?

Comment: sounds like impedance mismatch.  In other words, your expectations and desires regarding the database server doesn't quite match what the server actually does.  As you've noted, @@ROWCOUNT is counting the number of attempts (I'm guessing this is the number of INSERTs your code actually issues) rather than the number of successes which occur during trigger execution.  If possible, you might be better off refactoring a bit to remove the trigger.  Triggers are not evil, but they can bite you when and where you least expect it.  In my experience, "That trigger is best which does least".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some statements may change @@ROWCOUNT inside the trigger.

Statement

```
SELECT * FROM INSERTED WHERE COL1 < 5
```

executes and set @@ROWCOUNT to 1

Put statement

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

then

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED WHERE COL1 < 5)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    INSERT INTO dbo.ACCOUNT_CREDITS (COL1, COL2)
    SELECT COL1, COL2 from INSERTED
END
```

Comment: The truth is the only statement in the trigger that should affect @@ROWCOUNT is the insert itself.  I updated the example based on your observation.  The SELECT in the EXISTS test doesn't actually occur in the actual statement.  As I noted, I've "tried with NOCOUNT ON and OFF".  It doesn't seem to have an effect.  @@ROWCOUNT always reports the number of rows that attempted an insert, not the number that were actually inserted.

Comment: It turns out that the DONE_IN_PROC value returned to the client is the sum of all records affected.  The best solution was to SET NOCOUNT ON in a procedure that did the updates, then SET NOCOUNT OFF in the trigger itself.  This returns the actual number of records inserted by the trigger.  Your answer was close to what I was looking for.  Thanks:)

Comment: @Laramie and Lex: I realize this was asked 4 years ago, but if you are still interested in the answer, there is in fact a more direct way of passing this (and other) information along. Please see the answer I just posted :).

Answer (score 2):

### The Problem

I need information in the context of the main process that is only available in the context of the trigger.

### The Solution

Whether getting `@@ROWCOUNT` or anything else *from* a trigger, or even passing information *to* a trigger, there are two methods that allow for sharing information with triggers:

- [SET CONTEXT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx) / [CONTEXT_INFO()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx)
- Local Temporary Tables (i.e. tables with names starting with a single `#`: `#tmp`)

I posted an example of using `CONTEXT_INFO` in an answer on a related question over at DBA.StackExchange: [Passing info on who deleted record onto a Delete trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82615/passing-info-on-who-deleted-record-onto-a-delete-trigger/82627#82627). There was a discussion in the comments on that answer related to possible complications surrounding `CONTEXT_INFO`, so I posted [another answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82615/passing-info-on-who-deleted-record-onto-a-delete-trigger/82693#82693) on that question using a temporary table instead.

Since that example dealt with sending information *to* a trigger, below is an example of getting information *from* a trigger as that is what this question is about:

**First:** Create a simple table

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.InsteadOfTriggerTest (Col1 INT);
```

**Second:** Create the trigger

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_InsteadOfTriggerTest
   ON dbo.InsteadOfTriggerTest
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Trigger (starting): ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @@ROWCOUNT);

   SET NOCOUNT ON; -- do AFTER the PRINT else @@ROWCOUNT will be 0

   DECLARE @Rows INT;
   INSERT INTO dbo.InsteadOfTriggerTest (Col1)
      SELECT TOP (5) ins.Col1
      FROM inserted ins;

   SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
   PRINT 'Trigger (after INSERT): ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @Rows);

   -- make sure temp table exists; no error if table is missing
   IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TriggerRows') IS NOT NULL)
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO #TriggerRows (RowsAffected)
      VALUES (@Rows);
   END;
END;
```

**Third:** Do the test

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TriggerRows') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TriggerRows;
END;
CREATE TABLE #TriggerRows (RowsAffected INT);

INSERT INTO dbo.InsteadOfTriggerTest (Col1)
   SELECT so.[object_id]
   FROM   [master].[sys].[objects] so;

PRINT 'Final @@ROWCOUNT (what we do NOT want): ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @@ROWCOUNT);

SELECT * FROM #TriggerRows;
```

Output (in Messages tab):

> Trigger (starting): 91
>   Trigger (after INSERT): 5
>   Final @@ROWCOUNT (what we do NOT want): 91

Results:

> RowsAffected
>   5