# SQL Server procedure design to get results and results count in a single call

Tags: sql-server, count, multiple-results

I have a requirement where I need to pull the top 100 of the data result set and also the count of the records of the total data which satisfy my filtering condition.

Thanks,
Manoj.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an output parameter to return the total number of records and also a `select` statement that returns a result set.

For example:

```
create procedure test
   @totalCount int output
 as begin
     select * from something -- your select statement goes here
     select @totalCount = 'write your statement that counts the records.'
 end
```

If you need to call it from code, here's a `Java` example to illustrate how you would make the call:

```
public void test(Connection con) throws SQLException{
    CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("test");
    //you can set more parameters if you need to, i.e.: cs.setInt(0,id);

    //you need to register your output parameter. If you are referencing it by name, it should match with the name given in the stored procedure.
    cs.registerOutputParameter("totalCount", Types.INTEGER);
    ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
       //you can save the data into a data structure; a list for example.
       //Or just print the records.
    }
    //here's how you can get the total count
    int total = cs.getInt("totalCount");
}
```

**This method is just an example to show you how to make the call. Don't write production code like this!!!**

Comment: @Manoj, if this answer solved your problem please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It will help others to find correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

One of my answers is similar to A2H, ***but if*** your "count" is directly related to the query of your select, you can avoid a "double hit", but placing the results in the #temp table.

However, you can also use the @@ROWCOUNT trick as well.  Which is a  new answer, IMHO.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SelectAndCountExample
   @TotalCount int output
 as 

BEGIN

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Holder') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #Holder
end


CREATE TABLE #Holder
(SurrogateKey INT, SomeValue VARCHAR(64) )


/* simulate your insert */
INSERT INTO #HOLDER (SurrogateKey , SomeValue) 
select 101 , 'A' union all select 102, 'B'  union all select 103, 'C'  union all select 104, 'D' 

/* optional stuff */   
/* CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_TempHolder_ID ON #Holder (ID) */
/* CREATE INDEX IDX_TempHolder_ID ON #Holder (ID) */

Select @TotalCount = count(*) From #Holder

Select SurrogateKey , SomeValue from #HOLDER


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Holder') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #Holder
end


END

GO


declare @MyVariable int
EXEC dbo.SelectAndCountExample @MyVariable output
Select @MyVariable as '@MyVariable Value'



GO
```

and

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SelectAndCountExampleUsingRowCount
   @TotalCount int output
 as 

BEGIN


select 101 , 'A' union all select 102, 'B'  union all select 103, 'C'  union all select 104, 'D' 

Select @TotalCount = @@ROWCOUNT


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Holder') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #Holder
end


END

GO


declare @MyVariable int
EXEC dbo.SelectAndCountExampleUsingRowCount @MyVariable output
Select @MyVariable as '@MyVariable Value'
```

Comment: In your solution, the `@TotalCount` and the number of records returned is always the same. I don't think this is what @Manoj wanted. He wanted top 100 rows and the count of all rows that satisfy the criterion.

Comment: I'm giving the poster (and future readers) different options.  Obviously, if the result rows does not match what the count should be, there will be 2 different queries....which is why I upvoted your response.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. My answer was more of a layout of key points, didn't include any implementation (it is up to the implementer, how he/she wants to go about it), and you provided examples of an efficient implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon to need to page through results while also showing the total number of possible pages of results, and there are likely quite a few questions on here already about this. Unfortunately, there is no built-in mechanism to handle this. That leaves you with only a few options:

1. Run the query twice: once to get the total number of rows, and then again to get the subset / page of results that is needed. The downside here is that you are running it twice. (this is the basis of @A2H's answer)
2. Run the query once, dumping the results into a local temporary table and capturing the number of rows that went into the temporary table using `@@ROWCOUNT`. Then, SELECT the subset / page of results that is needed from the temporary table. The downside here is that you are taking a hit on IO (tempdb datafile and transaction log), though that might be possible to be improved by using In-Memory OLTP. (similar to @granadaCoder's answer, but that answer doesn't follow-through on the subset of rows requirement)
3. Build it into the app-code:

   - declare a counter to keep track of the total number of rows
   - run the full query
   - call `SqlDataReader.Read()` (assuming you are using .NET) -- without actually retrieving any of the data -- for the number of rows to skip, then read the rows for the subset / page of results that is needed, and finally call `SqlDataReader.Read()` -- again, without actually retrieving any of the data -- until there is nothing left to read. Increment the row counter in each of the 3 sections.

   Please see the following answer of mine, also on StackOverflow, that provides more details (and variations) on this approach:

   [TSQL: Is there a way to limit the rows returned and count the total that would have been returned without the limit (without adding it to every row)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070104/tsql-is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-rows-returned-and-count-the-total-that-would-h/27074033#27074033)